# a directory that can't be seen on command line but is visible on nautilus; and that cannot be deleted

Tags: nautilus, directory, inode

Inside my video directory I've noticed today a new directory called [...]mp4__QhYixM
I can see it when I open the video directory on Nautilus, but it's invisible on Nemo and via command line.
On Nautilus, its properties are listed as
Type | Folder (inode/directory)
Contents | unreadable

I've tried to delete it with Nautilus, but I fail. Any ideas?

Comment: does it disappear when you press Ctrl+H when in that directory?

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

That is a temp file used normally by an application like video player (rarely) or some editor, or if you are copying files for example with rsync.
Sometimes those files are left there if app creating them is abruptly ended.

In most cases you can remove them with sudo or as root user

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In this case, I cannot remove with sudo because I cannot see this file/directory in the command line in the very first place. I launched nautilus as a root, but then I cannot see it, either. It only appears when I launch nautilus as a normal user.

Comment: But what is the exact name of the file.  Very strange not to be seen by root.  Normally if file name starts with .  it will be hidden. so if you do `ls` it won't show  you have to do `ls .*`

Answer (score 1):

You mention a "video directory" that might still mean the default XDG "Videos" directory, which is normally a subdirectory of the `/home/<YOURUSERNAME>/` path. This home directory, as tradition, is often placed to a dedicated disk partition, separate from the operating system's files.

I would use the `lsblk -e 7` command to list the disks and their partitions to identify the disk partition of the home directory. (if nothing listed with `home` next to it, then possibly it's still on the same partition with the OS; in that case it's designated with `/`).

Having established the identifier of the curious partition, one can grab an Ubuntu live USB, and boot from it. It makes it easy to use the computer with the main disk's partitions unmounted.

It's important that they are unmounted, because that's a condition for using the `fsck` file system utility on a given disk partition.

Now it is possible to run the `fsck` disk utility on the partition, to see whether anything is in need of repair (fsck can carry out the repairs too).

---

**Warning:**

Running `fsck` manually, due to the severe impact of any mishap, is an event worthy of the highest caution. (There is a risk of data loss.)

That's why first I would by all means ensure that all the important content of the partition subjected to the manual fsck scan is safely backed up to another disk partition, or a separate disk, or a separate device.

I will not provide specific options or arguments for the `fsck` command here, since I am not well-enough versed in it. I [leave the man page instead](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck), and suggest that you search the web and read a few tutorials/articles about it. I say it's worth it: `fsck` is a highly valuable tool; it just demands extra respect from its user.